# Excel 2007 VBA Macro Stops when userform called

Tags: excel, vba, show, userform

I've been building a macro for a few weeks, and all of a sudden part doesn't work properly.  When I try to call a userform via .Show, for some reason the marco stops running right there and then, and highlights the ".show" line.  (Even if I jump to the userform box, the buttons are not functional.)  If I press F5 it starts to run again, but I obviously don't want the code to stop running in the middle of the program.  Any idea why this could happen, especially when it didn't used to happen?

Comment: If you want the macro to continue after showing the userfomr then try this `Userfomr1.Show VBModeless` If it is some other problem then post the code of `UserForm_Initialize()` if you have it

Comment: Your suggestion worked, sort of.  It allowed the macro to keep running, but I needed to fill in some of that data before next steps, so things went slightly amuck.  I am not sure where the userform_initialize() is located... I am not sure what is going on with this code- all of a sudden I am having a bunch of strange issues. I may be using too much memory with some of the worksheets I have open.  I will get back to you on this.  Thank you!

Comment: Can you share your excel file? If you are using the userform to collect data before running the macro then do not use `VBModeless`.

Comment: I can but it probably won't help you any because you need another file which I cannot give out in order to run it properly. would you still want to see it? (And closing the other files didn't help.  Maybe the file is too long- I have 675 lines of code and not enough are cut into functions.)

Comment: Yup. I am actually interested in the userform code...

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/13320/discussion-between-user1408660-and-siddharth-rout)

Comment: You can upload the file in www.wikisend.com and then share the link here?

Answer (score 0):

It turns out I had a bug in my code, which was hiding because I did not remove a previous "On Error Resume Next."  Many thanks to Siddharth!

Answer (score 0):

It is possible that the OP's concluded answer is not connected to the question, but is coincidental.

I had the same thing. Code stopped on frm.show for aboluteamente no legitimate reason. It was as though there was a Stop there. I tried everything but the solution was, unequivocably, to reboot.

I know it's a level one answer, but it truly did fix the problem here. I'm hoping that someone will save themself googling and spitballing 100 irrelevant solution attempts when, as stupid as it is, just rebooting fixes it.